# Something's wrong with the Skeptics logo on the network moderators page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With Google Chrome 17.0.963.79 on Windows 7, the logo for the Skeptics site on the [network moderators page](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) appears way too large:

> [image: skeptics]

I smell a conspiracy.

Comment: They're proud of that new site design, I see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks, this is fixed now. I uploaded too large favicon image. Had no idea it was used this way on the site.

Comment: "I" - are you a dev or something? How could you upload favicon?

Comment: @Martin: [Yes](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/skeptics-brand-concept-and-site-design)

Comment: @CodyGray: Ah. From when aren't devs listed as mods?

Comment: @Martin: Well, [Jin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) isn't listed as a moderator either. They're just on the creative/design team, I'm not sure if that counts as a "developer".

Comment: Allowing them to use a moderator tag like [meta-tag:status-completed] for things they do, would make sense, even if they aren't developers. Community coordinators have a diamond, even if they aren't developers.

Comment: @kiam: Apparently they *can* apply moderator-only tags. The posts on SE 2.0 beta meta sites by Jin announcing the rollout of the new theme have the `[featured]` tag applied, without requiring moderator intervention.

Comment: @CodyGray Link, or it didn't happen. `;)` Lately, I have not seen Jin adding any of the moderator tags to any question.

Comment: @kiam: [On Philosophy.SE](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/333/new-beta-theme-launched); I just noticed it this afternoon. I don't see anything in the history indicating collusion.

Comment: @Sean -- This does ***not*** seem to be fixed...

Comment: I only push to a dev server. There is a build process, and I'm not sure if when it goes out. From what I understand favicons and some other things are hard to clear out of a browsers cache. So hard resets, etc may be needed for curent changes to show.